# Getting files using expect command in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, expect

I am trying to automate SFTP command using a UNIX shell expect script with the help of expect command. My code is as below. When I tried executing the script it throws me an exception. Can somebody help me if you have faced the similar issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
--Shell Script

  #This ftp script will copy all the files from Buxton directory into the local directory.

#!/usr/local/bin/expect
spawn sftp -b cmdFile XYZ@sftp.abc.com
expect "password:"
send "6n8W6u0J"
interact

Command File

SRC_DIR='From_Bux'
TRGT_DIR='/work/informatica/release81x/DEV2/DEP_EXT_ARCH/SrcFiles/LANDING'
FILE='buxt_summary_20140702.csv'
cd $SRC_DIR
lcd $TRGT_DIR
get $FILE
Execution command ./get_bxtn_src_files.ksh

Error Message

$ ./get_bxtn_src_files.ksh
./get_bxtn_src_files.ksh[3]: spawn:  not found
couldn't read file "password:": no such file or directory
send: unable to stat draft file /home/vvutukuri/Mail/6n8W6u0J: No such file or directory
./get_bxtn_src_files.ksh[6]: interact:  not found
```

Comment: Are you sure you have spawn installed? Or the file cmfFile exists and is accessible?

Comment: My cmdfile exists and it is accessible to my code. I am getting spawn error.. How do I know whether it is installed or not... I am working on this script at my work location...

Comment: What OS/distro are you running. What's the output of `cat /etc/*-release` and `/usr/local/bin/expect -v`

Comment: And what shell are you in. You can see it with i.e. `echo $0`. Running your script with `csh` will give pretty much that output - version depending.

Comment: I am using korn shell (ksh)

Comment: Here is the o/p of your commands. $ $ cat /etc/*-release
cat: cannot open /etc/*-release
$
$ cat /usr/local/bin/expect -v
cat: cannot open /usr/local/bin/expect
$

Comment: `uname` should give you a hint of what OS you are running. You've written below that expect wasn't installed after all, which explains your issues. I would've thought you would get an error about missing interpreter, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an interpreter issue.

Check again if you script has `#!` as the to **absolute** first characters in your script.

```
head -1 get_bxtn_src_files.ksh | cut -c 1-2
# The result should be: #!
```

If not, the script will be interpreted with the shell you are logged in with.

The errors you are receiving indicates that the expect commands are interpreted by a regular shell (ksh/sh/bash/...) instead of `expect`.

See the following examples:

```
$ ksh
$ cd test
$ cat expect1-test.exp   # the hash-bang is in my first line
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sftp -b cmdFile XYZ@sftp.abc.com
expect "password:"
send "6n8W6u0J"
interact
$ ./expect1-test.exp    # Notice the error messages, they come from Expect
spawn sftp -b cmdFile XYZ@sftp.abc.com
No such file or directory (cmdFile).
send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"send "6n8W6u0J""
    (file "./expect1-test.exp" line 4)
$ cat expect2-test.exp   # Notice the blank line

#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sftp -b cmdFile XYZ@sftp.abc.com
expect "password:"
send "6n8W6u0J"
interact
$ ./expect2-test.exp   # Notice that i.e. spawn is not found.
./expect2-test.exp[3]: spawn: not found [No such file or directory]
couldn't read file "password:": no such file or directory
./expect2-test.exp[5]: send: not found [No such file or directory]
./expect2-test.exp[6]: interact: not found [No such file or directory]
```

You should also look into `autoexpect` which you can use to create an expect script you can use and edit.

Finally: You should consider switching to using ssh private/public keys instead of expect, unless - of course - you are prevented from doing this / need to use a password.

## SSH private/public keys

### On the remote machine

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.ssh/
chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh/
chmod go-w $HOME     # NB! If sshd is set to strict your $HOME - and parent directories must _not_ be world writable
```

### On the local machine

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.ssh # Create the .ssh directory if necessary
chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh  # Low perms to protect the directory
ssh-keygen -t dsa -f $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa -N ""   # Create the private/pulic key pair
                                               # with no pw since you'll use it in a script
scp $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.pub remote_machine:.ssh/authorized_keys  # Provided it's not allready there, in which case you should add your public key to the bottom of the file
```

Verify that you are able to log in withouth a password:

```
ssh remote_machine  # or user@remote_machine
```

Your script can now be:

```
#!/bin/ksh
# Or /usr/bin/ksh..?
sftp -b cmdFileXYZ@sftp.abc.com
```

On the command line you can also use

```
scp XYZ@sftp.abc.com:$SRC_DIR/$FILE $TRGT_DIR/
```

---

Comment: Yeah looks like I dont have expect installed on my unix box.. Also I dont have permission to install it... I have tried ssh as well.. but it didnt work... :(

Comment: `ssh-keygen` on your local machine. Then copy the contents of the .pub file into $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote machine, on a single line. Keep .ssh on `chmod 700` permission.

Comment: I generated the keys using ssh -keygen -t dsa and copied the public key into the remote server dir location. After that I tried doing ssh Username@servername.com but it still asks me for the password.

Comment: Move the pub file to the .ssh folder on the remote server and rename it to authenticated_keys

Comment: Great.I am able to connect now... How do I copy the files from remote to local? Is it just cp command?

Comment: New edit. If this solves your issue I would appreciate if you accepted my answer.